# PATH prismic command not found in my bash

Tags: javascript, git, bash, prismic.io

I am getting this :

```
-bash: prismic: command not found
```

and when i tried to see and fix it i got this below PATH. I want to change it but every time i do nothing change.

```
echo $PATH

/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myname/.rvm/bin
```

I tried to use export using these commands :

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

But nothing change. I am tying install Prismic using this command:

```
npm install -g prismic-cli
```

it work then i try to use this command :

```
prismic init whatevername
```

I get this error every time

```
-bash: prismic: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the binary for `prismic` is not in your path.

First find out where it is:

```
sudo updatedb
locate prismic
```

Then add that directory to your PATH.

Comment: Hey @Bruno  sudo updatedb i got this from the first command : sudo: updatedb: command not found and for the second command locate prismic
 i got this : WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bruno9779 says the binary has not been found in any directory on your PATH. What you need to do is find the residing directory of the "primsic" binary and add it to your PATH. To find the binary you can use any search tool. Bruno mentions locate but you could also use find:

`find / -type f -name "prismic"`

Once you have found the directory containing the "prismic" file you need to add it to your PATH using the export command:

`export PATH=/some/directory/bin:$PATH`

where you obviously substitute "/some/directory/bin" with the path to the directory containing the "prismic" file.

EDIT 15:01 GMT 30/01/2017:

Prismic installs it's binaries into the 'node_modules/.bin' directory therefore Hesham was adding the wrong directory to his path and hence the command was not being found.

Comment: hey flouc i tried to do what you both guys did but i still get the same error : export PATH=/Users/heshamelmasry/node_modules/prismic-cli/bin:$PATH . and then i wrote this . : -bash: prismic: command not found

Comment: @HeshamElMasry whats the output of doing: `ls -al /Users/heshamelmasry/node_modules/primsic-cli/bin`

Comment: hey this is my output : total 72
drwxr-xr-x   12 heshamelmasry  staff    408 Jan 30 15:54 .
drwxr-xr-x  550 heshamelmasry  staff  18700 Jan 30 15:54 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 heshamelmasry  staff    100 Nov 14 13:17 .babelrc

-rw-r--r--    1 heshamelmasry  staff  11357 Oct 26 15:44 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--    1 heshamelmasry  staff   1222 Oct 26 15:44 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   13 heshamelmasry  staff    442 Jan 30 15:54 bin

-rw-r--r--    1 heshamelmasry  staff   3718 Jan 30 15:54 package.json

Comment: pwd
/Users/heshamelmasry/node_modules/prismic-cli

Comment: Oops maybe do: `ls -al /Users/heshamelmasry/node_modules/prismic-cli/bin | grep "prismic"` looks like the character limit has truncated your answer.

Comment: -rw-r--r--   1 heshamelmasry  staff    156 Jan 10 11:54 prismic-configuration.js
-rwxr-xr-x   1 heshamelmasry  staff  13250 Jan 10 11:54 prismic.js . i got this

Comment: @HeshamElMasry there is your issue. That directory doesn't actually contain the prismic binary. I think the directory you need to add to your PATH is: /Users/heshamelmasry/node_modules/.bin